# nginx SSI: how to echo html?

Tags: nginx, html, server-side-includes

As a sanity test, at the head of my HTML page, I'm trying to do a very simple SSI `echo` to indicate to the browser that SSI is working:

index.html:

```
<script>var ssi_enabled = false</script>
<!--# set var="test" value="<script>ssi_enabled=true</script>" -->
<!--# echo var="test" -->
```

then later in JS:

```
if (!ssi_enabled) { console.log("SSI is not enabled!"); }
```

But when nginx `echo`es the string, the HTML tags are sanitized as follows:

```
&lt;script&gt;ssi_enabled=true&lt;/script&gt;
```

I can't find anything in the nginx docs that indicates how to `echo` raw HTML.

Yes I know I could import a html file, but was trying to avoid it as that adds more complexity.  Seems like this could be done but I'm just missing the correct parameter for `echo`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**nginx** has an `encoding` parameter to the `echo` command (cf. [supported commands](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands)), which decides how to escape the text. It can have three values **none** (which is what you are looking for), **url** and the default **entity**. Compare the results of:

```
<!--#set var="GREETING" value="<h1><strong>Hello <em>&World</em></strong></h1><p>àäáąåǎâ</p>" -->
<!--#echo var="GREETING" encoding="none" -->
<!--#echo var="GREETING" encoding="url" -->
<!--#echo var="GREETING" encoding="entity" -->
```